# is the placement of the "to be" verb correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

which is correct in terms of placing the "are":

1. The higher the percentage of the working-age population to total population, the larger **are** the private savings.
2. The higher the percentage of the working-age population to total population, the larger the private savings **are**

thank you

Comment: There is a close vote calling this a 'proofreading' question.  However, this is not a proofreading question because it identifies one very specific area of concern: the position of a single word!  Please do not misuse the close reason this way.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your comments right. to clarify my concern, I wish to know if using the "are" verb is correct at the end of a sentence. I've read on this site that it is ok to have a verb at the end of a sentence in English, but my concern is about the construction of  such sentences making a comparison between two things ...

Comment: Lower and higher savings; not larger. :)

Comment: @Han Thank you for clarifying.  I'm sorry my comment was unclear.  Someone cast a 'close vote' on your question, and I was responding to that person.  You can feel free to ignore my comment, but we do appreciate the clarification :-)  If you have anything you'd like to add to your post, please feel free to use the [edit] feature to put it in the post directly rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It goes to the end, but you're also missing an 'is' right before the comma. So correctly:

The higher the percentage of the working-age population to total population **is**, the larger the private savings **are**.

Comment: I don't think the **is** is needed in the first phrase, idiomatically.  For example, ["The bigger the hair, the closer to God"](http://www.southernbellesimple.com/2013/03/the-bigger-hair-closer-to-god.html) or ["the sooner the better"](http://sentencedict.com/the%20sooner%20the%20better.html).

Comment: If I omitted _is_, I would omit _are_ too. Like in your examples there is no _to be_ at all. I feel like Han's sentence is easier to understand with the _to be_ s, cause of its length. Your examples I find more difficult to "get lost" in. But correct me if using only the  _is_ or only the _are_ is correct as well.

Comment: @stangdon you did'nt mention if the "are" verb  should be  at the end or not.. the example you used doesnt have a verb.. thank you for elaborating